# How to find if Item language is falling back to another language?

Tags: multilingual, language-fallback

We have a multilingual website and using language fallback(Item Level). I am finding hard to get the fallback language of an item.

We have fr-FR which is falling back to en-FR. But when I get the item in fr-FR and check for

> LangugaeFallbackEnabled field is **false**

I could not find any other fields specifying this information.

I have double checked in Sitecore it's falling back to en-FR.

What's the best way to check for the fallback language of an item?

Sitecore Version - 8.1 update 3

Comment: With language fallback, accessing the item in the language that is falling back should give the item in the fallback language without any extra checks. Is that not working or are you trying to check if the item is falling back vs not for a specific reason?

Comment: Its giving me the item in falling back language. I am trying to check if item is falling back because I need to execute some logic if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if an item you are accessing is a fallback use the `IsFallback` property:
`Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.IsFallback`. To get the actual language being used you could use the method `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.GetFallbackItem()` and check the language on that.

It's possible that you could do this more efficiently while looking at that method by using the language fallback manager:
`Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageFallbackManager.GetFallbackLanguage(Language language, Database database, ID relatedItemId)`.

Comment: Is there a way to find which language it is falling back to?

Comment: You can try using this method: `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.GetFallbackItem()`. Then you would check the Language property of what that returns. I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Actually, that did not help, isFallback property is false and GetFallBackItem is null?

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri can you verify that accessing the item while your context language is set to the language that does not have a version has its fields filled with the content of the language it falls back to? Another thing I would like you to try running is the following: `Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageFallbackManager.GetFallbackLanguage(Language language, Database database)`. This should return your fallback language. If it does not then I believe there is an issue with how that is configured (`/sitecore/system/Languages`).

Comment: This is giving correct values - Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageFallbackManager.GetFallbackLa‌​nguage(new Sitecore.Globalization.Language("en-IN"), currentItem.Database) but on item level its not giving any? Language fallback is working correctly else where in website. I am running this on item:processed event. Does that causing the issue?

Comment: It's not even giving correct field values either unless its shared field.

Comment: I have checked the context language and it's "en" I have tried changing it to en-IN and context site from publisher to website. Still no change.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? This doesn't sounds like a language fallback issue, it sounds like a site/language context issue.

Comment: On Publish I am hooking an event on item processing event and try to execute a logic on an item based on its language. I think you are right, context site 'publisher' is not passing in all the info about the item but just the shared fields. I have tried testing it on 'Website' context and all seems to work as expected. Somehow I need to find the fallback version exists or not on itemProcessing event.

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri this answer I had earlier might help you get the right site :) 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/7253/1436. You might have to use a language switcher as well as a site switcher but I'm not positive. The site's default language might end up switching the context language inside the site switcher. Be wary that this might end up making publishing slow.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer as it actually is the right answer for the question initially asked. Thank you.

Comment: Alright sounds good. If the linked question doesn't help out feel free to post a new question focused on your issue.