How to tell if the item language is the fallback language or the regular language version
How to tell if the item language is the fallback language or the regular language version using a PowerShell script

Check this article - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/how-to-find-if-item-language-is-falling-back-to-another-language

Thank you for your posts. I tried many different ways. But many cases did not work.
The following steps worked.
# Iterate over all languages of the item
foreach ($language in $item.Languages) 
{
   # Get the item in the current language
   $itemInLanguage = Get-Item -Path $item.Paths.Path -Language $language

   # Check if count greater than 0 or not
   if ($itemInLanguage.Count -gt 0) {
       Write-Host "version found in language: $language"
    } else {
       Write-Host "no version found or fallback version in language: $language"
    }
 }


Language fallback can be checked by the Item.IsFallback property, which returns true if the item is a fallback item.
I didn't test it in Powershell but you can try it by the IsFallback property.

You can check item is a fallback item, through reading IsFallback property available on the item as below.
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{{Item_ID}}"
Write-Host $item.IsFallback

This will return true if the item is a fallback item.
Hope this helps!!!
